# Is it feasible to "shrink" an LP?

Tags: linear-programming, convex-geometry, polytopes

Suppose we have a nonempty polytope given by $P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}:Ax \leq b\}$. Does there exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that $P'=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}:Ax \leq b - \overline{\epsilon}\}$ is nonempty, where $\overline{\epsilon}$ is the vector whose components are all $\epsilon$?

This seems reasonable geometrically, but I'm not sure how to prove it analytically. I can also imagine that there might be some edge cases where this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple counterexample, consider $n=m=1$, $A=(1)$, and $b=0$.  Then $P=\{0\}$ is nonempty, but $P'$ is empty for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: This works, thanks, but do you happen to know what happens if we drop the non-negativity condition?

Comment: You can express nonnegativity as an explicit constraint, absorbing it into $A$.